# Inner Join not working and left Join taking to long to execute query

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables

- #temp (Trx, Mobilepin)
- Orders (SKU)

Now trx and mobilepin column of `#temp` table both match with SKU column on orders table

I am trying to join both tables but it's taking so long. And if I use inner join then nothing gets joined.
And if I use one inner join and one left join then it returns incomplete data.

```
select
    t.trx,
    t.MobilePin,
    o.SKU

INTO #CaseFOUR  FROM dbo.Order_No AS n 
    JOIN dbo.Orders AS o ON n.Order_No = o.Order_No
    left JOIN #Temp AS t1 ON t1.mobilepin= o.SKU
    left JOIN #Temp AS t ON t.Trx = o.SKU
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result from your sample data.

Comment: `but it's taking so long` ... are you using indices on the join columns?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What is the execution plan of the slow query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post, it doesn't seem like a left join is what you want. 
try this to only return orders that have *mobilepin* or *Trx* link.

```
select
    t.trx,
    t.MobilePin,
    o.SKU
INTO #CaseFOUR  
FROM dbo.Order_No AS n 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS o ON n.Order_No = o.Order_No
    INNER JOIN #Temp AS t1 ON (t1.mobilepin= o.SKU OR t1.Trx = o.SKU)
```